# How to fix websocket error: Error during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Tags: javascript, python, websocket

I want to create a web socket using Python and JavaScript, but I get the following error. thank you

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:1386/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Python Code:

```py
from socket import *
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(("localhost", 1386))
s.listen(5)
client, addr = s.accept()
print("connected to "+ str(addr))
client.sendall("hi. im server".encode())
client.close()
```

JavaScript - HTML Code

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <script>
        var socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:1386');
    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just because you have a socket at that port does not make it a WebSocket. WebSockets requires a series of protocol specific handshakes before the connection is established.

Comment: hello. What should I do now?

Comment: You could look up the WebSocket specs and implement the correct protocol or you could try to find a python library that already implements that protocol.

Comment: If you are using python > 3.6 there is this library https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html

Comment: very very thankyou

Answer (score -2):

**Error during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET**

Try to change '**ws**://localhost:1386' to '**wss**://localhost:1386'

ws   >>>   wss

Comment: The protocol name is not the problem here.